# Is it possible for WinZip to not recognize passwords created with a different WinZip version?

Tags: encryption, passwords, zip, winzip

I have a .zip file which came with a "supposedly" correct password to extract it. Yet neither 7-zip not my WinZip trial version recognize that password as correct. The same happens with password-cracking tools such as Advanced Archive Password Recovery. Does it mean the password is just wrong? Or is it possible that some programs don't recognize passwords generated with, say, the paid version of WinZip? I find it strange that the password is wrong, since that site uses that same password for most of its uploads.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it mean the password is just wrong?

Yes

> Or is it possible that some programs don't recognize passwords generated with, say, the paid version of WinZip?

The two formats, the current version of WinZip support, are supported by the trial installation of WinZip.  The license status of WinZip does not prevent you from extracting an encrypted protected archive.

> I find it strange that the password is wrong since that site uses that same password for most of its uploads.

You confirmed it was wrong since you used 7-zip, which would have worked, if the password was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered a situation that i zipped a file (with password) with a newer version of winzip-winrar-7zip but i can't open it with an older version of these application.